# Sending Voltage is higher than receiving voltage: Parallel Load Problem

Tags: three-phase, transmission-line, power-engineering, single-phase, homework

I had a problem on an exam which reads as follows:
[image]

At the end of the day, I got that the sending end voltage is lower than the receiving end voltage, which I know isn't possible. I think I may have approached the problem the wrong way. But it is somewhat possible that the question just has incorrect/unworkable numbers. I know that in the original problem I have the sign of the third power angle wrong, but even when I change that the sending voltage is still lower than the receiving voltage. Here is my work:

[image]

[image]
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Very bad quality question, the SI system dictates spaces around all number and the correct capitalisation of units. It should read as follows:  "Three loads are connected in parallel across a 4160 V RMS line supply.  The loads are as follows:  load one is 20 kW and 26 kvar, load two is 60 kW at 0.8 pf lagging and load three is 100 kVA at 0.9 pf leading."

Answer (score 1):

Load one is \$S= 20\$ kW and \$+j~26\$ kvar.

Load two is \$S=60\$ kW and \$+j~60\sqrt{({1\over 0.8})^2 - 1}\$ kvar.

Load three is \$S=90\$ kW and \$-j~100\sqrt{1-0.9^2}\$ kvar.

Now you can calculate the current using \$({S\over V})^* = I\$. You need to use the complex conjugate here!  (If you want to know why, long story please ask in comment. :-)

The voltage drop (rise) is \$V_l = Z_l\cdot I\$, giving:

$$V_s = 4146 \angle 0^o+V_l.$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be S*/V* ?

Comment: No, maybe?  \$S = V\cdot I^*\$ so, oops \$I^* = {S\over V}\$ my bad!  I will fix it.  Thanks!